# GUI image display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, random

This is the code that I made for displaying random cards. The random card selection is working fine, but the images are not displaying.

Why is this happening?

```
public class RandomeCard {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int CardNumber = 54;
    int i;
    int Num;
    int FirstNum=0;
    int SecNum=0;
    int ThirdNum=0;
    int cnt = 1;
    int numbersNeeded=0;
    int max = 0;

    for(i=1; i<=CardNumber; i++){
      Num = (int)(Math.random()*54)+1;

     if(i==1){
       FirstNum = Num;
       System.out.println("Fist card number "+FirstNum);
     }

     if(i==2){
       SecNum = Num;
       if(FirstNum == SecNum){
           i++;
     } else {
           System.out.println("Second card number "+SecNum);
          }
     }   
     if(i==3){
       ThirdNum = Num;
       if(FirstNum == SecNum){
           i++;
     } else {
       System.out.println("Third card number "+ThirdNum);
     }
    }

 }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Card Display");
    frame.setSize(300, 200);

 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
 frame.setVisible(true);
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("card/.png");
 JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
 frame.add(label);
 frame.add(new jlbl(new icon1("card/"+FirstNum+".png")));
 frame.add(new jlbl(new icon1("card/"+SecNum+".png")));
 frame.add(new jlbl(new icon1("card/"+ThirdNum+".png")));
}

  private static class icon1 {

    public icon1(String string) {
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon();
    }
}

private static class jlbl extends PopupMenu {

    public jlbl(icon1 icon1) {
        JLabel jlbl = new JLabel();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing command line and GUI code?  Where are the images stored with relationship to the source?  Why are you extending `PopupMenu`?  Why not just add the `JLabel`'s to the `JFrame`  directly?

Answer (score 3):

None of your classes bind together.  `icon1` loads an `IconImage`, but then does nothing with it, you create a `JLabel` in `PopupMenu`, but don't add it to anything...

Simply add the `JLabel` to the `JFrame`

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("card/"+FirstNum+".png")));
```

This assumes that the images are stored in a directory called `card` which is located at the same location as the program is executed.

You might find `ImageIO.read` a better choice for loading images, at least it throws an `IOException` when things go wrong.

Take a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: Thankyou. I tried your code but its not working, still images not displaying

Comment: As I said *"This assumes that the images are stored in a directory called card which is located at the same location as the program is executed"* - Since I don't know where your images are stored, this is the best I can do